# How to avoid classify all data to one class?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I sometimes meet the problem that when I use CNN to classify multi-class data, say class A, B, C, D, all the data are classified to one of the class ( So that the accuracy is around 0.25 ).

That's definitely not a data problem because a significant difference when I do two-class classification between each two of them.

Sometimes the problem comes because I choose too small learning rate, that's somehow easy to understand why, but sometimes,

```
Epoch [1/5], Iter [100/4688] Loss: 1.3861, Batch correct: 0.2676, Correct: 0.0053, At time: 0.23
Epoch [1/5], Iter [200/4688] Loss: 1.3872, Batch correct: 0.2480, Correct: 0.0106, At time: 0.47
Epoch [1/5], Iter [300/4688] Loss: 1.3869, Batch correct: 0.2285, Correct: 0.0160, At time: 0.70
Epoch [1/5], Iter [400/4688] Loss: 1.3860, Batch correct: 0.2578, Correct: 0.0213, At time: 0.95
```

And my learning rate is 0.1 and using nn.CrossEntropyLoss(). So is it still a learning rate problem?

Can anyone explain why this problem occurs and what should I do to overcome it?

Comment: Could you add a bit more information? What kind of data are you using? Are you only training for a fraction of an epoch? Whats the difference between `Batch correct: ` and `correct`?

Comment: Check how you labelled the data. For example, if you have labelled class A,B,C,D as 1,2,3,4 and such problem occurs if you have not done the necessary transformation for the softmax to understand. Instead try like class A,B,C,D label as 00,01,10,11.